# Pass parameters to Azure DevOps tasks depending on the trigger with YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML Pipeline in Azure DevOps that uses different triggers:

- Continuous Integration
- PR Completion

This pipeline uses VsTest to execute UnitTests, and i would like to have different parameters depending on how the pipeline was triggered, i.e:

- Enable code coverage and run only on impacted tests if the pipeline is triggered for PR completion
- Run all the tests if this is for continuous integration

Is there any environment variable i could use to use to affect different values to my variables (both are Booleans).

I couldn't find any environment variables in Microsoft documentation that refers to how the pipeline was triggered.

I could use two different pipelines with different YAML configurations, but that's not ideal.

Thanks for your time and your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) the env variable `Build.Reason`:

**Manual**: A user manually queued the build.

**IndividualCI**: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in.

**BatchedCI**: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in, and the Batch changes was selected.

**Schedule**: Scheduled trigger.

**ValidateShelveset**: A user manually queued the build of a specific TFVC shelveset.

**CheckInShelveset**: Gated check-in trigger.

**PullRequest**: The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that
requires a build.

**BuildCompletion**: The build was triggered by another build

**ResourceTrigger**: The build was triggered by a resource trigger or it was triggered by another build.

So in your steps add the corresponding condition, for example:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))
```